# zsh "cd.." command stopped working without space (cd<space>..)

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

"cd.." stopped working without space.

I used to type "cd.." but since the last update only "cd .." works
it throws:

```
zsh: command not found: cd..
```

how can I get it back?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an alias

```
alias cd..="cd .."
```